# Limit supremum of the sum of two non negative sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Assume that $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ are sequences with non-negative terms. Then $lim sup (a_n + b_n) = lim sup(a_n) + lim sup(b_n)$? I think it is true since if not then we will most likely have an infinite number of $(a_n + b_n$)’s bigger than some $x > lim sup(a_n + b_n)$ which is a contradiction, am I right?

Comment: Consider the counterexample$$a_n=\begin{cases}0&n\text{ even}\\1&n\text{ odd}\end{cases}$$$$b_n=1-a_n$$which gives the "equality"$$1=1+1$$

Comment: @PeterForeman Thanks. what if we had them both be strictly positive?

Comment: Use the same example but add one to both sequences.

Comment: For the infimum using the same counterexample works.